# How To Make Cursor Position Move Faster

Tags: jquery, cursor, tracking, polling, wii

I've been experimenting with using my Wii U gamepad to control my PC and have been hitting a few roadblocks. I first tried to use an application called Usendmii but the button and cursor update polling rate is only at 50ms from what I have read. That is definitely not fast enough and results in super stuttery gameplay on anything that requires the camera to be moved around.

So I moved on to other options and found GamepadToPC.rar which was written by Chris Manning. It solves the stuttering issue but results in a cursor that tracks across the screen extremely slowly. I've been trying to find a way to edit the source code, but it's written with node jQuery and HTML. I don't have a ton of experience in jQuery or node so I think there is a setting that I'm missing just from looking at the HTML files.

It's also important to note that I've increased the windows cursor sensitivity to max and in-game sensitivity as well.

Please help!

Because there are a couple of files here is the link (***just click on April 1st***)

https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://lhite.com/wiiu/GamePadtoPC.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to mention a few things about UsendMii. Since version 0.1.0, the WebSocket protocol is used to transmit data from the Wii U Internet Browser to the PC. For that to work, you will need to have Wii U update 4.0.0. Without this version, POST requests are used.

So what it means is that if you have newer version of the software you could transfer the button states at each 20ms. Without that, it will be set to 40ms.

If you need to test that, simply start the application with the `-d` switch. At the bottom you will see the average time for an HTTP request.

Current version of UsendMii is 0.2.3 and by the way it has a Mouse Speed setting.